# Mac mini A1347 fan at full speed after booting and no video signal

Tags: startup, video, mac-mini

After pushing the power button of my mac mini, the cooling fan goes to max speed and does not put out any video signal. The Power LED is on and white.

- I removed the power cord and cleaned the fan and the inner of the mac -> no change
- I tried to remove both RAM sticks and boot -> mac beeps once every couple seconds and the fan seems to be on normal speed. But still no video Signal.
- I tried to boot with only 1 RAM stick -> Still fan ramps up to the max and no video signal.

UPDATE

- I tried every possible combination of RAM position and I get the same issue. Fan on ful speed and no video signal.
- Also tried to use the apple key combinations during startup as sugested but nothing happens.

Even if it is a HW failure, I would love to understand where the failure is located, so that I could do a visiual inspection with microscope and x-rax (we have one in the company).

Does anyone have an idea what I could troubleshoot next?

I am thankful for any ideas and comments.

Regards

Comment: you tried each RAM stick by itself in one of the slots?

Comment: No, I only tried one RAM Stick in one slot and not all possible combinations. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Add your results to the original question!

Comment: Have you only tried normal boot or all the different startup modes: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Comment: Thank for the hint! I will try this, but I don't have an apple keyboard but a windows keyboard. Can I also get to this modes with a windows keyboard?